# How use existing connection in Logic Apps Designer

Tags: azure-logic-apps

When I create a new Logic App and choose, for example, "SFTP file is added or modified" I am prompted to add the connection information. I have already created an API connection to my SFTP server. How to choose this existing connection instead of creating a new one in Designer? Or do I have to switch to Code View in order to use an existing connection?

Update: I tried in code view to copy over my connections ( the "$connections" element from another Logic App) and go this error:

Operation failed: The template validation failed: 'The template parameters '$connections' are not valid; they are not present in the original template and can therefore not be provided at execution time. The only supported parameters for this template are ''.'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that the new Logic App has to be in the same region as the existing API Connection.

Comment: Yes currently connections are filtered in designer by region and resource group. However we are working on lifting that restriction so any connection in your subscription could be used. If you use visual studio designer you do get a template you can use as well to create or use connections. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: 4 years later; is this still the case?

Comment: 5 years later; this still appears to be the case: same region and resource group (at least when using the designer).