# When will the restriction that Azure API connections are filtered on the resource group in the Azure Logic App Designer be lifted?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Azure API connections are filtered on the resource group in the Azure Logic Apps Designer. @jeffholan stated that this restriction will be lifted in a comment on an answer to the following question [How use existing connection in Logic Apps Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079031/how-use-existing-connection-in-logic-apps-designer). Does anyone know when?

Comment: this question should raised on azure forums

Comment: @Mr.Arjun, I have recreated the question here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1417e1bb-c96a-4e51-b980-b5a4ade7a3a9/when-will-the-restriction-that-azure-api-connections-are-filtered-on-the-resource-group-in-the-azure?forum=azurelogicapps. Should I simply delete this one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a connection from a different resource group today by updating code view directly or deploying via ARM templates but it is not yet supported in the designer.